# Make only two empty line spaces between each sentence on RichTextBox.

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have more than 100 lines in a RichTextBox. Some of the lines are empty and some of them has a sentence. I want to make only two empty line spaces between each sentence in the RichTextBox. How would I do that?

```
List<string> rt = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
   if (line != "")
   {
       rt.Add(line);
   }
}

richTextBox1.Lines = rt.ToArray();
```

Comment: call rt.Add("") directly after rt.Add(line)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, tested and works fine (not very efficient though)

```
List<string> rt = new List<string>();
bool doAdd = true;
foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    if (doAdd)
    {
        rt.Add(line);
        doAdd = true;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
          doAdd = false;
    }
    else
    {
         if (!doAdd)
           rt.Add(line);
         doAdd = true;
    }
}
richTextBox1.Lines = rt.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not be able to test this, but you can certainly try this

```
        List<string> rt = new List<string>();
        string content = richTextBox.Text;
        foreach (string line in content.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))  //checks if the line is empty
                continue;
            rt.Add(line);
            rt.Add("\r\n");  //makes a new line
            rt.Add("\r\n");   // makes another new line
        }
```